# typescript Cannot GET / error

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, typescript

I need some help on typescript(I'm a totally noob in typescript). I've stuck on this problem more than 10days but couldn't solve. I guess I'm lost at all. Your help will be truly precious for me.

I'm trying to use google map api for web.
This is my code:

baisc.ts

```
///<reference path="../typings/globals/google.maps/google.maps.d.ts" /> 
var limit = 0;
var markers =[];
var labels="12345"; 

/*
var opts: {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-36.850,174.763);
zoom: 14;
}; */

module Mapping {
export class GoogleMap {

    public name: string;
    public map: any;
    public options: any;

    constructor (mapDiv: Element){
        this.name="GoogleMap"; 
        this.options={center: new google.maps.LatLng(-36.850,174.763),zoom: 14}; 
        this.map= new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, this.options);

        google.maps.event.addListener(this.map,"click",()=> {
            this.addMarker(event.currentTarget, this.map);
        });
    }
   }
```

And this is index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <!--identifier of HTML5 -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">  
    <title>Here!</title>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=listMarkers"></script> 

    <script defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY"></script> 
    <script src="./js/second.js"></script>   

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script type "text/javascript">
        function initialize(){
            var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
            Mapping.GoogleMap(mapCanvas); 
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" id ="page-container">
        <h1 id="app-name">
             Here!
        <span src ="./image/placeholder (1).png"></span> 
        </h1>

        <h2 id="page-header">
            Mark simply and make assure your meeting spot with friends. 
        </h2>

        <body onload="initialize()">
        <div id="map">map</div> 
 <p>The markers' locations are: </p>


        <pre id="output1"></pre>
        <pre id="output2"></pre>
        <pre id="output3"></pre>
        <pre id="output4"></pre>
        <pre id="output5"></pre>

    </div>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
    <script src="./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

when I run this code, I got Cannot Get/ error. Anybody knows what to do?

Comment: I'm not familiar with typescript, but do you need to define the `event` argument in the click handler function?  `google.maps.event.addListener(this.map,"click",(event)=> {`

Comment: Also where/what's the `this.addMarker` function?

Comment: You may want to check the [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1033708/Learning-Typescript-and-building-a-google-map-with) about typescript and Google Maps API. You may not have configure the setting/function correctly. You may also want to check [Angular Google Maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/). Typescript is a 2-year old powerhouse language, and is ordained as the official language for Angular js 2.0.